# Upload video from dropbox to vimeo using vimeo API

Tags: php, jquery, dropbox, dropbox-api, vimeo-api

> **Hello Everyone,**
>
> I am trying to upload video on `VIMEO` using 'jquery API`. It's proper working, but i want to upload video from "DROPBOX" to "VIMEO". Is there is any jquery or Php API for uploading video from dropbox to vimeo.
>
> Thanks in advance

Comment: Vimeo and Dropbox allow this via the respective websites.
Go to: https://vimeo.com/settings/apps and allow Vimeo access to your Dropbox account and select whichever directories you require.

https://vimeo.com/help/faq/uploading-to-vimeo/uploading-from-dropbox#how-does-automatic-uploading-from-dropbox-work For more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more programmatical way, you will need the following steps:

1. Set up a [dropbox app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) and check out [their libraries](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php).
2. You will then need a vimeo app which needs permission from the vimeo staff (write a short description and send it via email). Vimeo has [a library as well](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php).
3. You will need the user tokens from Dropbox and Vimeo respectively.
4. The simplest way is to send a pull request to vimeo. See [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos) for more details.

If this is too complicated, there also is a [webservice](http://boxconnect.org) for that.